# Dataset is not connected Anyone agrees with me?

Tags: ado

I think dataset is not connected .You can close db connection and open other connection, update dataset data to other database. Anyone agrees with me?

Comment: This looks like there might be a question in there somewhere. Not really sure what it is though.

Answer (score 0):

A dataset is kind of a structure of your database, just in memory. But you are right, the dataset itsself is not directly connected to a database